# Beginner sql student in need of assistance

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I'm very new to sql, and Stack Overflow. I'm hoping someone can help assist me in this query. My query is supposed to display the total sales and total items sold for categories with more than $200,000 in sales. I've been working on this query for an hour and am at my wits end, and help is appreciated!

```
   select distinct c.categoryname,
   sum(p.unitprice * od.Quantity) as 'Sales'
   from Categories c
   inner join Products p
   on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
   inner join OrderDetails od
   on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
   where p.unitprice < 200000 
   group by c.categoryname
```

I'm hoping I'm at least on the right track, thanks for the help!

Comment: You are filtering those products that have a unit price of *less than* 20000, why is that?

Comment: it would probably be `sales > 200000` instead of unit price

Comment: @prashanth - I gave your suggestion a try and I received this error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'sales' to data type int." Thanks anyways for trying!

Comment: my bad.. it compared the string `"slaes"` instead of `sum(p.unitprice * od.Quantity)`! so, instead of p.unitprice, you could use, `sum(p.unitprice * od.Quantity) > 200000` and its `>` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
SELECT
   c.categoryname,
   sum(od.Quantity) as "Items Sold",  -- you were missing this
   sum(p.unitprice * od.Quantity) as "Sales"
FROM
   Categories c
   INNER JOIN Product p ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID,
   INNER JOIN OrderDetails od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
WHERE
   sum(p.unitprice * od.Quantity) > 200000  -- filter on the sales, not product
GROUP BY
   c.categoryname
```

Comment: This got me off in the right direction, I had to make a change by using this line    having sum (p.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) > 200000   thank you for the help! @Burhan

Comment: @user7701115  you may upvote the answer that helped you! or mark as answer if you cannot upvote!